# box shadow overflow parent

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a sidebar block with an inset shadow. I want the shadow to appear on top of the `.block-title` element, but the shadow is rendered under it.

You can see the problem here: **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4fkfdxn6/1/)**

This is my css:

```
.block{
  width:250px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 7px 0 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 7px 0 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 7px 0 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border:1px solid gray;
}

.block .block-title{
  background:#dedede;
  padding:5px;
}

.block .block-title span{
    color:#333;
  font-size:14px;
  text-align:center;
}

.block .block-content{
  padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Your first sentence is a bit jumbled.

Comment: You could simply apply the same box-shadow to `.block-title`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the box shadow on top of the children using an absolutely positioned pseudo element (`::before`). Use `poiner-events: none` on the pseudo element to allow interaction with the elements under it.

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.block::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 7px 0 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  pointer-events: none;
  content: '';
}

.block .block-title {
  background: #dedede;
  padding: 5px;
}

.block .block-title span {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.block .block-content {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-title">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span>
  </div>
  <div class="block-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam efficitur elit quis auctor sollicitudin. Aenean est lorem, ornare in laoreet sed, lobortis ac libero. Phasellus dignissim imperdiet varius.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is that `.block-title` is covering the shadow effect. You could make the effect appear a bit more if you added `opacity`, or gave the `color` an `rgba`-value.

I changed the hexidecimal color to `rgba` in my example.

**JS-Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/4fkfdxn6/4/

**html**

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-title">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span>
  </div>
  <div class="block-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam efficitur elit quis auctor sollicitudin. Aenean est lorem, ornare in laoreet sed, lobortis ac libero. Phasellus dignissim imperdiet varius.
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
body{
  margin:10px;
}

.block{
  width:250px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 7px 0 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 7px 0 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 7px 0 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border:1px solid gray;
}

.block .block-title{
  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /*changed this value*/
  padding:5px;
}

.block .block-title span{
  color:#333;
  font-size:14px;
  text-align:center;
}

.block .block-content{
  padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you can apply a suitable shadow on the .block-title element.

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward solution I can see is to also add the box shadow to your title, see here:

```
body{
  margin:10px;
}

.block {
  width:250px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 7px 0 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 7px 0 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 7px 0 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border:1px solid gray;
}

.block .block-title {
  background:#dedede;
  padding:5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 7px 0 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 7px 0 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 7px 0 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.block .block-title span{
    color:#333;
  font-size:14px;
  text-align:center;
}

.block .block-content{
  padding:10px;
}
```

Others have posted similar answers but I believe this is more elegant and easy to understand.